# Raw HTML in HelperList column

Tags: html, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a `HelperList` in Prestashop (1.6) with a few columns/rows. One of the columns is an anchor element (`a href`), and I need to show it like that in the list, but Prestashop escapes the value and represents it as a literal string.

How can I show an actual anchor element in one of the columns of a `HelperList`?

Plus: I'd like to not have to override PS classes nor copy the entire template just to change a single line of code. I do know how to do it using either of those ways, but I'm looking for something less "aggressive".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this trick:

```
$fields_list = array(
    'your_link' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Your title'),
        'type' => 'bool',
        'float' => true, // a trick - prevents from html escaping
        // else code
    ),
);
```

Comment: Very nice trick! Indeed, that works. I hope PS never patches this :)

Comment: Spot on - saved my bacon !